# Using a variable as timeout for OS Process Sampler generates Java exception

Tags: jmeter

Using a defined variable ${runtimems} as Timeout for OS Process sampler generates the error below when saving saving the variable (${runtimems} as Timeout in the testplan? The variable looks ok  (60000) when printing it to console in runtime.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${runtimems}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:694) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:831) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.system.gui.SystemSamplerGui.modifyTestElement(SystemSamplerGui.java:136) ~[ApacheJMeter_native.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentNode(GuiPackage.java:494) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentGui(GuiPackage.java:452) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:75) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:65) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]´´´

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Wqv.png
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a limitation in JMeter, you can [request an enhancement](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) via Github

---

In the meantime you can use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as the workaround.

1. Leave "Timeout" field blank
2. Add JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the OS Process Sampler
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   sampler.setTimout(vars.get('runtimems') as long)
   ```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)